# Oracle WCC Set Date Field to Null With RIDC

Tags: java, oracle-ucm

I'm trying to make an update to an **Oracle WCC** Server VIA an ***RIDC*** Java based application.

I've tried: `dataObject.put("dOutDate", null);` However that just returns:

> Unable to update the content item information for 'My_Content_ID'. The expiration date is not valid. Unable to parse date 'null'.

So how can I update a Date Field to be NULL for a *Content Item* using **RIDC**?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully update by passing in " " instead of NULL.
So now my code looks like `dataObject.put("dOutDate", " ");`

I'm not sure that's the best approach, but it worked.

Comment: Did you try just leaving out the dataObject.put for dOutDate? Otherwise, I think setting to "" is just fine.